# Total possible number of fantasy football roster combinations from total team of 15 players

Tags: combinatorics

How many possible fantasy football lineup combinations can I create, from my roster of 15 players?

I have a fantasy football roster that consists of:

- 2 QB's
- 4 WR's
- 4 RB's
- 2 TE's
- 1 Kicker
- 1 DEF

How many lineups can I create, which each lineup consisting of:

- 1 QB
- 2 WR's
- 2 RB's
- 1 TE
- 1 Flex (which is a WR or RB)
- 1 Kicker
- 1 DEF

I am not sure how to account for the FLEX position. Without the flex, I understand 3x4x4x2x1x1 = 96, but when I account for the FLEX I begin to double count. For example, if I have RB-A in the RB position, and RB-B in the FLEX position - if I create a lineup with RB-A in the FLEX position and RB-B in the RB position, that wouldn't be a unique lineup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 choices for QB and for your TE, and one choice for your K and DEF.

You also have $\binom{4}{2}$ choices for each of your WR and RB, and then 4 choices for the FLEX player from the remaining WR's and RB's.

This gives $2\cdot2\cdot6\cdot6\cdot4=576$ choices (assuming the FLEX player is specially designated).

There are only $2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot4\cdot6=192$ choices  if the FLEX player is simply a 3rd RB or a 3rd WR, though.

Comment: Where is the 3 QB number coming from? I have 2 QB's on my roster, to fill 1 QB spot in the lineup. 2 Tight Ends on my roster, to fill 1 TE spot in the lineup. Would it then be  2⋅6⋅6⋅4⋅2⋅1⋅1?

Comment: Sorry - I miscopied the number of TE's available, so I have to change that; but your problem seems to indicate that there are 3 QB's on the roster.  Is one player on the team designated as a FLEX player, or is that just an extra RB or WR?

Comment: There are 2 QB's on the roster, but the lineup can only start 1 QB. The FLEX is essentially an extra RB or WR, yes. So if RB-A starts at RB, and RB-B starts at Flex, if you swap those 2 (RB-A to Flex and RB-B to start at RB) it is not a unique lineup, that is where I was having difficulty calculating the total number of unique possible lineup combinations

Comment: Sorry, I just saw my error with typing 3 QB's

Comment: Thanks for this information; based on what you said, I think the 2nd answer is the one you want.(I'm adding the cases 3 RB, 2 WR and 2 RB, 3 WR.)